# Proper JSDoc typedef declaration of function with optional arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript, webstorm, typedef, jsdoc

Given following typedef

```
/***
 * @typedef {object} Queue
 * @property {function(string):string[]} listQueueNames Gets an optionally 
   filtered list of QueueNames. 
 */
```

What is a proper way to mark listQueueName's Argument as an optional Argument ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Closure Compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#optional-argument-in-a-function-type) syntax should work here:

```
/***
 * @typedef {object} Queue
 * @property {function(string=):string[]} listQueueNames Gets an optionally 
   filtered list of QueueNames. 
 */
```